# NullPointerException when trying to @Autowired WorkerThread

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, autowired, applicationcontext

I have my main Application annotated with @SpringBootApplication. Here is the code for the following:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

        @Autowired
        public ExternalConfiguration configuration;

        @Autowired
        WorkerThread workerThread;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(new Object[] { Application.class });
            springApplication.run(args);
        }
    }
```

And here is my **WorkerThread.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    ExternalConfiguration externalConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    WorkerConfig workerConfig;

    WorkerQueueDispatcher dispatcher;

    public WorkerThread() {
        dispatcher = applicationContext.getBean(WorkerQueueDispatcher.class, externalConfiguration.getEventQ(),
                workerConfig.getWorkers());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("Worker thread started. Thread ID :" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        dispatcher.run();
    }
}
```

I tried debugging and found out that my **ApplicationContext** was not getting Autowired and is null.

I haven't used **new** for instantiating the WorkerThread.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Obviously I know what a NullPointerException is. I am talking about ApplicationContext not getting @Autowired and hence it is null. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Please provide stack trace when NPE is thrown during accessing application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using autowired fields in constructor here:

```
    public WorkerThread() {
        dispatcher = applicationContext.getBean(WorkerQueueDispatcher.class, externalConfiguration.getEventQ(),
            workerConfig.getWorkers());
    }
```

Constructor is called by spring before it is able to inject these dependencies. Therefore they are all `null`.

You have two options:

1. Do your initialization in `@PostContruct` instead of constructor.
2. Use constructor injection (it is good practice anyways)